# Codeigniter can't delete cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a login script, and now I am trying to build a logout for it. I am using both cookies and sessions within CodeIgniter, and despite doing the below, the cookies still manage to stick and I can't figure out why. Allegedly this is the way to kill cookies via CI but I logout, close the page, go to another page and `print_r($_COOKIE)` and they will still be there.

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
delete_cookie('LongRemember', '', '0');
delete_cookie('AutoRemember', '', '0'); 
redirect('m/logout', 'refresh');
echo 'logged out';
```

Comment: Does setcookie work? **setcookie("LongRemember", $value, time()-3600);**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [cookie helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) you can delete a cookie in two ways:

1. `delete_cookie("name");`
2. `delete_cookie($name, $domain, $path, $prefix);`

This function doesn't not accept expiry parameters.

Don't forget to load the helper: `$this->load->helper('cookie');`

Comment: cookie helper is auto loaded :-) but in other words Im basically on the right path just not doing it right. I wlll have to give this way a try, thank you